# Setting ApplicationID for every build variant

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-gradle-plugin

I need to set my application ID for a build variant.

I have a defaultConfig in my build.gradle, which sets the applicationId

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mycompany.mainappname"
    minSdkVersion 12
```

Now I need to set the application ID to `"mycompany.mainappname_fullversion"`. (no dot between mainappname and _fullversion)
I need this, because I have published my fullversion to googleplay 4 years ago with this name.

How can I do this ?

I tried to use the applicationIdSuffix syntax in my buildTypes Section to add the suffix, but it also adds me an "." befor the suffix, which is in my case wrong -> `"mycompany.mainappname_fullversion._fullversion"`

```
buildTypes {
       full {
          applicationIdSuffix '_fullversion'
```

I also tried to set the applicationID with applicationId `"mycompany.mainappname_fullversion"` in my build section, but i throws errors.

How can I simply set the applicationID to ""mycompany.mainappname_fullversion" in a build ?

Can someone help ?

Comment: I would suggest to use build flavours if the intent of the app is notably different in some way. E.g. paid vs free.

Answer (score 0):

Place a separate manifest in each build variant's directory under `src`.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `applicationId` from `defaultConfig` and add `applicationId` in each of `buildTypes`

```
buildTypes {
   full {
      applicationId 'mycompany.mainappname_fullversion'
```

Comment: No. See in my question. I already tried this before the answer. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Did you remove applicationIdSuffix from every where?

Comment: I am having this only in the build section of the appvariant (removed it from the defaultConfig), means only once in the file, but I get an error during building the project. Does this work for you ?

Comment: In my answer above I am using only **applicationId** and not `**applicationIdSuffix**`. Because I am providing `**applicationId**` value as a complete value **no suffix or prefix**.

Comment: I do also. I removed the suffix, because I dont need it if I set it with applicationId. Can you please tell me if it is working for you, so I can be sure it is possible that way, otherwise this is all very speculativ and confusing.

Comment: I damaged my laptop and setting up the new system. Will take time. But as far as I can recall it should work because loggically we are removing it from defaultConfig and using it in other places with inheritance of defaultConfig property .

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/95/gradle-for-android/402/adding-product-flavor-specific-dependencies#t=201702071121222914393